# Which functions in SQL are predicates?

Tags: sql

I know that SQL is different in various databases. But I need to know which functions are predicates in source SQL as language standart (not vendor solutions).
I found:

- `CONTAINS`
- `EXISTS`
- `IS NULL`
- `IS NOT NULL`

Is it all? Or did I lose smth?
Are all predicates use the TVL?
P.S. Sorry if I wrote stupidity, I'm a noobie in the database but I need to know it for exam.

Comment: What? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic) as sample.

Comment: Do you know functional/logical programming languages?

Comment: I would guess the actual question is, "Which SQL language features return a conventional truth value (true or false) rather than SQL's nulls-related three-valued logic (true or false or unknown)?" For example, `IS DISTINCT FROM` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` would be valid answers.

Comment: I need all. Although, I agreed with you that TVL-predicates are not same that mathematical predicates.

Comment: @onedaywhen, thank you! It's suitable for my question too. I'll group these predicates in two groups: predicates and TVL-predicates. Unfortunately, I don't know how to call it else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer here:

[ANSI SQL Framework](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=53681)

Comment: Sorry, I don't very good know English. Am I need to buy it?

Comment: I understood how to download) Thank you very much!

Comment: Дерзай на здоровье, чувак)

Comment: Спасибо, брат) Откуда русский знаешь? На переводчик не похоже

Comment: Хорошо, брат, спасибо! Давай, салам!